# How to show images and time them correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I hope the title is not misleading, but have this situation:

I want to to make that gif appears only if class exists. Now, I have three gifs, and I want each one to start its animation after the previous ends. How do I do this correctly?

I also want the first animation to start only when page is scrolled to its div, not before, as there is no point of showing the gif until the page is scrolled to its section.

I did try something, but it is not working..

```
if ($('.title-inner').hasClass('visible')) {
    $('.media').find("img[src$='/04/IC.gif']").show('2000');
}
```

What is the best approach to this?

Comment: can you plz post the html code

Comment: Just as a side note, it should be `hasClass('visible')`

Comment: You are right, give me a sec to test. I cannot post html, as it is wordpress and there is no use

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a gif has fully animated using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9314104/how-to-tell-if-a-gif-has-fully-animated-using-jquery)

Comment: I've edited the hasClass part, and it is still not working. No it is not duplicate, as I want to time the start of div appearance at all, not only the file.

Comment: Have you added any code which determines whether or not the element is in view? How is the `visible` class added?

Comment: visible class is added somehow when you scroll to that div. It is in Wordpress theme.

Comment: So you use timers to "end" the GIFs? Then why not use that timer to start the second, and so on? Also, why exactly cant you just combine all the GIFs?
That if condition also gets passed only once(since we don't see any code). Why not show the next after x amount of time, and 3rd after y amount of time, all relative to the first time?

Comment: JaredT, write a code how I can do that and I'll mark it as best if it works. I cannot, as one need to come after another. Images describe process in three major steps.